Finite Direct Sum in relation to Finite Direct Product - Additive Category
The question is have is admittedly very basic, but I struggle to find posts (on StackExchange) or proofs addressing it.
Let $A$ denote some arbitrary additive category. Hence, the direct sum $(X_1\bigoplus X_2,\{in_1,in_2\})$ corresponds with the direct product $(X_1\bigoplus X_2,\{pr_1,pr_2\})$ in a manner such that $(*)$ $in_1\circ pr_1+in_2\circ pr_2=\mathbf{1}_{X_1\bigoplus X_2}$ and $pr_\alpha\circ in_\alpha=\mathbf{1}_{X_\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in\{1,2\}$.
My question: Why are we able to make statement $(*)^1$? (In particular, I'm looking for a proof.) It feels very basic, but for some reason I can't come up with anything. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

$^1$The symbol $(*)$ refers to both equations.

The answer here shows that in additive category the product and coproduct coincide. Along the way, it checks that the relationships in your statement hold

@RhysSteele Perfect! Thank you so much. That's exactly what I was looking for. (I don't know how I couldn't find this earlier??)

See also the nlab page

@NaïmFavier I'll just be entirely honest and confess that nlab almost always leave me with more questions than answers. The site is a little beyond my comprehension levels for the moment. But thanks for the link! I really do appreciate it.

You may be interested in that, too! https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/
